# JSF Primefaces Galleria is duplicating photo ids

Tags: jsf, primefaces

JSF Primefaces Galleria is duplicating photo ids.

How can I get photos with distinct ids? My bean return a list of photo names (String)

```
<p:galleria value="#{imagesView.images}" var="image" panelWidth="400" panelHeight="300" showCaption="true">
    <p:graphicImage name="/img/#{image}" alt="Image Description for #{image}" title="#{image}"/>
</p:galleria>
```

Im trying to make my code w3c compliant.

Thanks

Comment: Actually you're right, even in the showcase Galleria is doing the same, maybe you might want to report it since I didn't find it in the [issues](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/list?can=1&q=Galleria&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Priority+TargetVersion+Reporter+Owner+Summary&y=5000&cells=tiles). In the mean time you can alter the ids using jQuery.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm gonna report this issue and look for an workaround.

Comment: They didn't accepted this as an issue. Said that there's no need to w3c compliance. ¬¬